# knockoutjs: how to recover from or trap a missing ko.observable() or ko.computed()

Tags: knockout.js

**BACKGROUND**

Trevor has a simple knockoutjs page with three declared ko.observable() and one declared ko.computed()

**PROBLEM**

Trevor would like to *remove* the third declared item. The problem is, when Trevor removes it, the rendering of all subsequent declared items fails as well.

**EXAMPLE**

Consider the following code fragment:

```
<p>r1c1:    <input data-bind="value: r1c1, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /></p>
<p>r1c2:    <input data-bind="value: r1c2, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /></p>
<p>r1c3:    <input data-bind="value: r1c3, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /></p>
<p>r1c4:    <input data-bind="value: r1c4, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var ViewModel = function(){
    var self    =   this;

    self.r1c1 = ko.observable('alpha');
    self.r1c2 = ko.observable('bravo');
    self.r1c4 = ko.observable('delta');

    // if Trevor comments out this line, it caues r1c4 to stop rendering
    // this is expected, but is there a workaround that does not require to
    // remove the data-binding to value r1c3 from the HTML body ?
    self.r1c3 = ko.computed(function(){return [self.r1c1(),self.r1c2()].join(':')});
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

**QUESTION**

Is there a way that Trevor can comment out the ko.computed() declaration for r1c3 and still leave the data-binding to r1c3 in the page body; without it breaking the subsequent data-binding to r1c4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick that Trevor can use is to reference the variable in the binding as `$data.r1c3` rather than just `r1c3`.  Referencing an undefined property of an object does not cause an error like referencing an undefined variable would.

So, Trevor would want to make his HTML look like:

```
<p>r1c3:    <input data-bind="value: $data.r1c3, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /></p>
```

Comment: Thanks RP, that makes perfect sense.